# Is there a way to update stock android file manager (com.google.android.documentsui)?

Tags: file-manager, android-11

Due to some reasons (I couldn't figure out why), my google default file picker has stopped working, it just crashed like end of the world.

After several attempts to fix it, i.e. clear cache & storage, force stop the app and its services, none actually helped. So I proceeded to uninstall the app updates, still, it doesn't work.

Is there anywhere I can download and update it? It ain't in Play Store.

Comment: I need the same thing. Here is the error I am getting: `Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{bcb8a9f 7794:com.google.android.documentsui/u0a67} (pid=7794, uid=10067) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs`